# PHP and css form validation

Tags: php

I'm looking to validate 2 x form fields. I can get the following class to output a message on screen. However, I want the class to kick out a variable that can then be used. Here's my code.

```
<?php

    class Validator
    {

        public $firstName;
        public $email;

        public static function Validate($firstName, $email)
        {

            if(!$firstName)
            {
    
                echo 'Name not Ok!';

                $this->error['firstName'] = true;

            }

            if(!$email)
            {
    
                echo 'Email not Ok!';

                $this->error['email'] = true;   

            }

        }

    }

Validator::Validate($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['email']);

?>
```

If the $this->error['firstName'] exists I want to change the colour of the form field to red. See below.

```
<?php if($error['firstName']){ echo 'style="border-color: red;"'; } ?>
```

Hope this makes sense. Vey new to oop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Where are you stuck? As you are already collecting all errors, why not read them along the form fields (which you haven't shared in your question)

Comment: Is there a specific error you want to mention? I would guess you've probably got one about using $this in a static context, for a start. Please always mention the specific issue/error when asking. You haven't really asked us a question, just stated a requirement without any contextual reference to the code you've posted

Answer (score 1):

You need your class to return true false for every error. It is also undesirable to do echo inside the validation class.
You cannot and should not use $ this in a static class. It is also necessary to create a new object for each validation.

```
 <?php

class Validator
{
    public $error = [];

    public static function Validate($firstName, $email)
    {
        return ((new self())->check($firstName, $email));
    }

    protected function check($firstName, $email) {
        if(!$firstName) {
            $this->error['firstName']['error'] = true;
            $this->error['firstName']['text'] = 'Name not OK';
        }

        if(!$email)
        {
            $this->error['email']['error'] = true;
            $this->error['email']['text'] = 'Email not OK';
        }

        return $this->error;
    }
}

$validate = Validator::Validate('test', false);

if (isset($validate['email']['error'])) {
    echo "<span style='color: red'>{$validate['email']['text']}</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Can you please explain what this element is? $validate = Validator::Validate('test', false); Thank you in advance.

Comment: @pugili5t this is test data, your need using $validate = Validator::Validate($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['email']);